# Struggling to create partitions on a SD flash card

Tags: partitioning, gparted, sd-card

I wanted to create partitions on a SD card. I tried to use GParted, KDE Partition Manager and also tried it under Windows using the system's manager but it always fails at creating more than one partition.

The Process starts normal but then fails at KDE Partition Manager and shows an error, it continues at GParted without error but in the end you can not find the partitions - they stay beeing undefinied space - Windows gives me the same struggle. The first partition all of these three are creating works perfectly fine, but then they all fail to create another one.

I have tried different formats: exFat, Fat32, NTFS, ext1,2,3,4 (encryption on and off). It's always the same result.
I have tried creating partitions with all the same type of format and tried to use mixed ones.

Partition tables I used were MS-Dos as well as GPT.

I have played around with space before and after each partition - no result.

Is it in general a problem to partitionate a sd flash card ?

Edit: I've also tried fdisk - without success. It creates just the first partition, the rest doesn't work.

Comment: Broken or fake size card ?

Comment: I do not think you can have a mix of different partitions on the same card. Other then that I was about to suggest the same thing @Marco did.

Comment: If I create just one partition with the full size, it works fine. If I start to create any sort of partition - only the first partition gets successfully created. No matter the size.

Comment: I have considered it being fake or broken. Actually should be a new card - I am using f3probe to test it at the moment. But since I can create a single large partition which appears to work fine, this might be not the cause.

Comment: Since the problem occurs both in Windows and Ubuntu, it is not an Ubuntu problem. The problem is in the card.

Comment: You write that it works to create one single partition. Create one with another file system than what was previously there. Reboot the computer and check if the result is what you tried to create, or if the card is still what it was before. - I suspect that your card is read-only, but seems to be working during the formatting process. You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the replies so far.
I used f3probe to find out that the card is damaged and further research brought up that I was delivered a fake sd card. It's not from the manufacturer that is printed on it. I wasn't considering that I actually was delivered a fake one.